# How to implement Single Sign-On (ADFS) in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, adfs, ws-federation

FYI: see update 12-FEB-2019

I have created an ASP.NET MVC application (using Visual Studio) and attempted to get it to handle SSO using an Active Directory Federated Server.  Note, this is **not** using Azure.

So, the first step works - I navigate to my login page and there's a button to allow me to log onto another service ["Federation"].  This launches the ADFS web page where I enter my credentials, but on returning to my website, I get the following error:

> IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: '[PII is hidden]'.
>   Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: '[PII is hidden]'
>   or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: '[PII is hidden]'.
>
> Exception Details:
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException:
>   IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: '[PII is hidden]'.
>   Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: '[PII is hidden]'
>   or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: '[PII is hidden]'.

Evidently, I've not got this set up right....so need to know what I'm missing...

Here is my (cut down) code:

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);    

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
        {
            MetadataAddress = "https://adfs.Mydomain.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml",
            Wtrealm = "https://myWebServer/myWebApplication"
        });
    }

    private bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslpolicyerrors)
    {
        return true; // Our "TEST" ADFS has a fake certficate, so we don't want to validate it.
    }
}
```

**Sections in the Web.Config**

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

    <add key="ClaimsNameIdentifier" value="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" />
    <add key="ClaimsUPNIdentifier" value="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn" />
    <add key="ClaimsEmailIdentifier" value="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.1" />
  </system.web>
```

(Note: in the authentication element above, intellisense gave me "Federated" as a option, but this results in a compile error).

One helpful resource was [alligatortek](https://alligatortek.com/blog/how-to-use-adfs-to-implement-single-sign-on-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application/), but that didn't really fill in all the pieces.  There are others resources that seem close, but not specific enough.

**UPDATE 12-FEB-2019**

Based on comments below, I was advised to instead follow [Vittorio Bertocci's post](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/) which uses the "On-Premesis" option (this is pretty much identical to [Rober Finch's post](http://work.haufegroup.io/haufe-adfs-identity-for-aspnet-login/)).  The resulting code is a bit different (see below) but the result is still the same.

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private static readonly string realm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Wtrealm"];
    private static readonly string adfsMetadata = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ADFSMetadata"];

    /// <summary>
    ///     Configures the authentication.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">The current application.</param>
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = this.ValidateServerCertificate;
        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = Startup.realm,
                MetadataAddress = Startup.adfsMetadata
            });
    }

    private bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslpolicyerrors)
    {
        return true; // Skips certificate validation as using a temp certificate.
    }
}
```

**Sections in the Web.Config**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:ADFSMetadata" value="https://adfs.Mydomain.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
    <add key="ida:Wtrealm" value="https://myWebServer/myWebApplication" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally solved this.

In the Startup.Auth.cs file, I temporarily added the following line to the ConfigAuth(...) method:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
```

This then showed me that I had to add a trailing slash to the "Wtrealm" value the web.config entry

So from:

```
<add key="ida:Wtrealm" value="https://myWebServer/myWebApplication" />
```

to :

```
<add key="ida:Wtrealm" value="https://myWebServer/myWebApplication/" />
```

Answer (score 3):

By far the easiest way to do this is via the "[On-Premises](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/)" option in VS.

Comment: I followed the "On-Premises" post (which does seem a better starting point than the "alligatortek" post I originally followed), but still getting the same error message when the ADFS returns to my application.  Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Can you access the ADFS metadata in your browser? Does ADFS have external access to get the certificate revocation list?

Comment: 1) I am able to access the metadata in my browser and from the servers required to access it, but only from  behind the firewall (it's not publicly available). 2) Not clear on the certificate revocation list...  3) The metadata contains a <ds:DigestValue>, a  <ds:SignatureValue> and the <X509Certificate>.  Other than that, it refers to the thumbprint (without providing it).  I was expecting the authentication framework to interpret all this and use it "as is".

Comment: The following [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/security/how-to-build-claims-aware-aspnet-mvc-web-app-using-wif) post shows far more configuration added to the web.config than was added using the [On-Premises](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/) link.  Not clear of Microsoft's post is out-dated.

Comment: Using "On Premises" essentially gives the OWIN stack the metadata address and it derives all the needed information from that. That's why the web.config is smaller.

Comment: The metadata contains the certificates. if you copied and pasted the certificate portion to a file and named it xxx.cer, clicking on that in Windows will display the certificate and you can get the thumbprint from that. But as I said above, you don't need to.

Comment: The CRL is used to clear out invalid certificates. If ADFS is not publicly available, it can't access the list. There is a Powershell option to turn this off in ADFS.